# React Dynamic Filtering to Filter the Card Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, select, react-router, dropdown

I am new to react, I am working on a project. I need little help regarding the filtering of the data. There are two filters one-: State and Location. The location is dependent on State, which is working fine, but after that, I want to filter my card component i.e VideoCategory card basis on above-selected value. There are three levels of filtering and for the third level, the filtering is not working.
Please, anyone, help me out, as I am trying to fix this issue from last two days.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Menu from "../common/Menu";

import { Form, Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  getVideosBasedOnCategories,
  getAllStates,
} from "./helper/userApiCalls";
import VideoCard from "../common/VideoCard";

const CategoryVideos = ({ match }) => {
  const [videoCategory, setVideoCategory] = useState([]);
  const [selectState, setSelectState] = useState([]);
  const [selectLocation, setSelectLocation] = useState([]);

  let location="";

  const preload = (categoryId) => {
    getVideosBasedOnCategories(categoryId).then((data) => {
      if (data.error || !data) {
        console.log(data.error);
        return <h1>No Data to Show Now</h1>;
      } else {
        setVideoCategory(...videoCategory, data);
      }
    });
  };


  //Intial Loading
  useEffect(() => {
    preload(match.params.categoryId);
    getAllStateForSelect();
  }, []);


  //getting data for first Select Component from API
  const getAllStateForSelect = () => {
    getAllStates().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.error) {
        return console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        setSelectState(...selectState, data);
      }
    });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setSelectLocation(event.target.value);
  };


  const onLocationChange=(event)=>{
    location = event
    console.log(location)
  }


  //Storing Location into Option for Second Select
  const onSplit = (x) => {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < x.citynames.length; i++) {
      arr.push(
        <option key={i} value={x.citynames[i]}>
          {x.citynames[i]}
        </option>
      );
    }
    return arr;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Menu />
      <Container style={{ marginTop: "200px" }}>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustom">
            <Form.Label>Select State</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              onChange={handleChange.bind(selectState[0])}
              custom
            >
              {selectState.map((data, index) => (
                <option name="setmap" key={index} value={data._id}>
                  {data.statename}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustom">
            <Form.Label>Select Location</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              onChange={(e) => onLocationChange(e.target.value)}
              custom
            >
              {selectState
                .filter((selectState) => selectState._id.includes(selectLocation))
                .map((e) => onSplit(e))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <Row>
          {videoCategory.filter(videocard=>videocard.location.includes(location.toString()))
            .map((videocard) => {
              return (

                <Col lg={4} xs={12} md={12} className="py-3 px-3">
                  <VideoCard videoCategory={videocard} 
                              />
                </Col>
              );
            })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryVideos;
```

VideoCategory File

```
import React, { Fragment,useEffect,useState } from "react";
import { Card, Button, Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import {getStateById} from '../user/helper/userApiCalls'

const VideoCard = ({ videoCategory }) => {
    const [state,setState] = useState("");
    const [city,setCity] = useState("");
  //const { name, link, description } = videoCategory;
  const getStateByFromVideoId = (stateId)=>{
    getStateById(stateId).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        if(data.error){
            return  console.log(data.error)
        }
        else{

           setState(data.statename)
        }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getStateByFromVideoId(videoCategory.state);

  }, []);
  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <iframe
        src={videoCategory.link}
        width="300px"
        height="300px"
        id="myId"
        className="myClassname"
        display="initial"
        position="relative"
        allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
      ></iframe>

      <Card style={{ width: "300px", }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{videoCategory.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{videoCategory.description}</Card.Text>
          <Card.Text>{state}</Card.Text>
          <Card.Text>{videoCategory.location}</Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default VideoCard;




 **UPDATE**
The API structure for State, which will reflect in card, the location is hardcoded, it doesn't have any id.


  {
            "_id": "5eb59d177693b6f99404f4c6",
            "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/NEIwl93Yr8o",
            "description": "LifeStyle",
            "name": "Testing",
            "state": "5eb564ec7693b6f99404f4c5",
            "category": "5ead7555fb5c440f458e625b",
            "location": "Kondapur",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-08T17:55:35.731Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-08T18:28:43.635Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
** The Filter of State and location(citynames) is :**
    {
        "citynames": [
            "ABC",
            "EFG"
        ],
        "_id": "5eb2ad8b554215be68773cf1",
        "statename": "Madras",
        "createdAt": "2020-05-06T12:28:59.149Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-06T12:28:59.149Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Comment: Can u provide the `videoCard` object values, also the state and location u mentioned

Comment: What kind if error you are getting?

Comment: @AkhilThakur...I am getting null values as no cards are shown up when I filter on the include conditions. {videoCategory.filter(videocard=>videocard.location.includes(location.toString()))
When I am hardCode any instead of location.string(), the filter is working suppose if hardcode it with 'ABC', the cards having location as ABC is coming but with the location.toString() it is coming as null. I checked in the console also the value is the same as the video card location object.  value.

Comment: @Kaslie, I have attached the object value file.

Comment: I don't see the object value file

Comment: @Kaslie, are you asking for the key, value pair elements for VideoCategory file

Comment: try this `videoCategory.filter(videocard=> videocard.location.includes(selectLocation.toString()))`.

Comment: @Kaslie, I tried above one but doesn't work, the screen is blank, I will post the screenshot of the output so that you can also refer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BI2xaNUqUUKXVNPaPd6dvZ1pQJSr1yjJ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--gZB6_fI7uhtYSp29rcB682yGtcCrSV/view?usp=sharing
@Kaslie

Comment: try hange your form location on Change to `onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}`

Comment: @Kaslie, ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined, getting this as error that's why I bind it there only.

Comment: My bad, Change to this `onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}` or u can write `onChange={handleChange}`

Comment: @Kaslie, thanks for your help, but the filter only works for first time(i am getting data only for first selected value after selecting), after that, the second drop-down gets locked and there are no values, and then filtering is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's i change some code, but there's also some notes i need to confirm first

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Menu from "../common/Menu";

import { Form, Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  getVideosBasedOnCategories,
  getAllStates,
} from "./helper/userApiCalls";
import VideoCard from "../common/VideoCard";

const CategoryVideos = ({ match }) => {
  const [videoCategory, setVideoCategory] = useState([]);
  const [apiStates, setApiStates] = useState([])
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState(null);
  // Change default value to '' i think
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState(null);

  const preload = (categoryId) => {
    getVideosBasedOnCategories(categoryId).then((data) => {
      if (data.error || !data) {
        console.log(data.error);
        return <h1>No Data to Show Now</h1>;
      } else {
        setVideoCategory(...videoCategory, data);
      }
    });
  };


  //Intial Loading
  useEffect(() => {
    preload(match.params.categoryId);
    getAllStateForSelect();
  }, []);


  //getting data for first Select Component from API
  const getAllStateForSelect = () => {
    getAllStates().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.error) {
        return console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        setApiStates(...apiStates, data);
        // remove this line
        // setSelectedLocation(data[0])
      }
    });
  };
  
  const onStateChange = event => {
    setSelectedState(event.target.value)
  }

  const onLocationChange= event => {
    setSelectedLocation(event.target.value);
  }


  //Storing Location into Option for Second Select
  const onSplit = (x) => {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < x.citynames.length; i++) {
      arr.push(
        <option key={i} value={x.citynames[i]}>
          {x.citynames[i]}
        </option>
      );
    }
    return arr;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Menu />
      <Container style={{ marginTop: "200px" }}>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustom">
            <Form.Label>Select State</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              onChange={onStateChange}
              custom
            >
              {apiStates.map((data, index) => (
                <option name="setmap" key={index} value={data._id}>
                  {data.statename}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustom">
            <Form.Label>Select Location</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              onChange={onLocationChange}
              custom
            >
              {apiStates
                .filter(apiState => apiState._id === selectedState)
                .map(value => onSplit(value))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <Row>
        // I'm curious about the location, is it array of string ?
          {videoCategory.filter(videocard => videocard.location === selectedLocation))
            .map((videocard) => {
              return (
                <Col lg={4} xs={12} md={12} className="py-3 px-3">
                  <VideoCard videoCategory={videocard} />
                </Col>
              );
            })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryVideos;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, because the _id is not the location, so you won't get anything of that filter

Comment: The id is a unique string it is not an array, and the location is an array. I am posting an update of both.

Comment: Yes, or u compare the name of the location

Comment: so then I have to compare for each and every name it's better I include location ID in the API.

Comment: Let me know the result

Comment: Sorry! The second dropdown is not loading at all with the above code, and I have updated the question also with your queries.

Comment: `videoCategory.filter(videocard => videocard.location === selectedLocation))` I've updated this line

Comment: is citynames is a location also ?

Comment: yes, the city name is location only. But sorry again the second dropdown is not coming

Comment: Could you please log this state `selectedState` ? also i've update my code a bit, on here` {apiStates
                .filter(apiState => apiState._id === selectedState)
                .map(value => onSplit(value))}`

Comment: selectedstate is showing the selectedStateID, and filtering is working fine now but the problem is that at initial page loading there is no card, as I  need to select the filter to show any cards on UI, can you tell me how can i make sure that initially everything loads up and then filtering will work. Btw thank You soo much.

Comment: To ensure everything loads up, use can create a `loading` state

Comment: Ya Thanks @Kaslie...It's working now..thank you soo much for your help. Thanks.